# How to select members of a custom datatype returned by a function as separate columns along with columns of a table.?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say there is:

- a table called `FOO` with columns `colA` and `colB`
- a custom data type with `BAR` with fields `f1`,`f2`,`f3`
- a function `BAZ` that takes two arguments and returns a single record of `BAR` type

I want to do this:

```
select f.*,BAR(f.colA, f.colB).* from FOO f;
```

I expect a result like this:

```
colA | colB | f1 | f2 | f3
```

Executing the above query gives a syntax error.

Executing the following query works:

```
select f.*,BAR(f.colA, f.colB) from FOO f;
```

but the entire datatype is serialized into a single column whereas I want each property of the returned object to be shown as a separate column.

Further, it would nice if I can select which properties I want to see from the object returned by `BAR(f.colA, f.colB)`without having to use`BAR(f.colA, f.colB)` multiple times in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing a pair of parenthesis around the call to `BAZ` :

With :

```
CREATE TYPE BAR AS (f1 integer, f2 integer, f3 integer);

CREATE FUNCTION BAZ (x integer, y integer) RETURNS BAR AS $$
  SELECT x, y, x+y
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

CREATE TABLE FOO (colA integer, colB integer);

INSERT INTO FOO VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2);
```

Then :

```
SELECT f.*, (BAZ(f.colA, f.colB)).*
FROM FOO f;
```

Returns :

```
┌──────┬──────┬────┬────┬────┐
│ cola │ colb │ f1 │ f2 │ f3 │
├──────┼──────┼────┼────┼────┤
│    1 │    1 │  1 │  1 │  2 │
│    1 │    2 │  1 │  2 │  3 │
└──────┴──────┴────┴────┴────┘
(2 rows)
```

---

If you want to reference the results multiple time, you can use a CTE :

```
WITH BAZ_TABLE AS (
  SELECT (BAZ(f.colA, f.colB)).*
  FROM FOO f
)
SELECT BAZ_TABLE.f3, BAZ_TABLE.f1
FROM BAZ_TABLE;
```

Returns :

```
┌────┬────┐
│ f3 │ f1 │
├────┼────┤
│  2 │  1 │
│  3 │  1 │
└────┴────┘
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

If version 9.3+ use the `lateral` join to avoid multiple function evaluation at each row as in `(baz(f.cola, f.colb)).*`:

```
select f.*, b.*
from
    foo f
    cross join lateral
    baz(f.cola, f.colb) b
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM